# Creating multiple arrays with different names in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

Trying to make a little chat program, I am currently using a `click` function to create new containers (new channels to chat in) and add them to my HTML page.

I want to add an array (the whitelist) to every container I create and name it in a way so that I can call it later, but the number of containers isn't limited so I'll have to do it with a variable or something.

I'm currently using one array for all of the containers; The code snippet:

```
i = 0;
$('#newroom').click(function () {
   chatroom = {};
   chatroom.whitelist = [];
   //making every whitelist unique here
   //here i am creating all the other stuff
   i++;
});
```

I want to call the whitelist later like

`document.getElementById('chatroom.whitelist' + i)`

or something similar, I just want to differ between the them to get the names stored in one specific whitelist.

I don't know if there's a more simple way for this since I'm new to Javascript but I sure do hope you'll help me.

Comment: You could simply make it an array of arrays. How are you planning to get that specific array?

Answer (score 0):

Your model does not need a unique id for every whitelist. Because you add your whitelist to the chatroom.

On the other side your code is not working when you want to do `document.getElementById('chatroom.whitelist' + i)`

Because with every click you want to add a new chatroom. After 10 clicks you have 10 chatrooms. If you want to select the 3rd chatroom, what are you going to do? So the id needs to be on the chatroom:

```
chatrooms = [];

$('#newroom').click(function () {
   chatroom = {};
   chatroom.whitelist = [];
   id = chatrooms.length;
   chatrooms.push(chatroom);
});
//select 3rd chatroom
chatr = chatrooms[2];
//get the whitelist
wl = chatr.whitelist;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following simple approach:
Let's say we have a main container for chat rooms with `id="chatroom"` and a customized button with `id="newroom"`. On every `#newroom` click we can add a unique block for every 'whitelist'.
**html part:**

```
<div id="chatroom"></div>
<div id="newroom">Add new room</div>
```

**js part:**

```
var counter = 0;

$('#newroom').click(function () {
   //making every whitelist unique here
   counter++;
   $('#chatroom').append("<div id='whitelist"+ counter +"'></div>");

});

// now you can access certain `whitelist` element by id:
var members = $("#whitelist3").text();  // exemplary case
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as is can understand you want to create sublists within the whitelist. One suggestion would be why don't you create properties within whitelist, these properties could be named after the distinguishable criteria that identifies each whitelist and then the value of all these properties could be your array of names.

It could be something like

```
chatroom = {};
$('#newroom').click(function () {
   chatroom.whitelist.distinctPropertyOne = [];
   chatroom.whitelist.distinctPropertyOne.push = 'name1';
});
```

Now you can access your separate whitelists using  chatroom.whitelist.distinctPropertyOne

Hope this helps.

Manan